# I cannot set my images to the same size in a row, with TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am using TailwindCSS to create the design of my page. I cannot set the components and the images to the same size.

I already tried some combination with flex, wrap, changing the width of the div or of the images, but cannot find a solution. What I would like to have as a result is the same size of rectangle that contains the images, the same size of images, for each movie, with the name of them below.
And, for the overflow, I want to be able to scroll them on the x scale but not on the y scale. I managed to do so, but I need to keep this and have the right sizes too.

I would like the images to be displayed like this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/16C7M.jpg)
But for now they are like this : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L0sD.png).

The code for one image is the same for all, only the link for the image and its name is changing. The code for one image :

```
<div
            class="bg-white rounded-[10px] border-4 cursor-pointer m-5 flex-wrap duration-500 w-1/6"
          >
            <img
              src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMWM5YzhmNGMtZTI4Ny00MGM4LThkYjAtMDIyMTEwNTQyZmQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
              alt="movie poster"
              class="rounded-t-[0.625rem] rounded-b-none w-full"
            />
            <div class="">
              <h1 class="text-xl font-normal">I am not okay with this</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And the previous code is contained in this following code :

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="m-5">
        <h1 class="text-3xl m-2 pb-1 font-bold text-black">Action</h1>
        <div class="flex overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll border-4">
        ....
        .... (put here the code for the images)
        ....
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you put the whole code of the image list in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

You need to write this line of code and here is the code below.

```
   <div class="flex overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll border-4">
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images /M/MV5BMWM5YzhmNGMtZTI4Ny00MGM4LThkYjAtMDIyMTEwNTQyZmQ1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg"
          alt="movie poster"
          class="rounded-t-[0.625rem] h-[300px] rounded-b-none w-full"
        />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your design calls for a specific shape i.e. you don't just want to view the image in its natural dimensions, I would try using [`object-fit`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit) (it's a [CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)) on the images. Set the size of the container for your images, then add the appropriate value for this property (probably "cover").

It essentially works as `background-position` but for images tags, not just css-set backgrounds.